# Accessing file from android data directory

Tags: android

i want to access the /data/local/tmp for any random access file
(RAF) file how to get the path of that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go this way and read the raf file line by line but be assure that the folder have read permission to other user or you can change it from adb shell by using chmod commmand .....

```
    File finalFile = new File("/data/local/tmp", fileName);
    RandomAccessFile rafTemp = new RandomAccessFile(finalFile, "r");
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the any file through code , you must know the path of the file. 
and then you can use the code:

```
File finalFile = new File/t("/data/local/tmp", fileName); 
RandomAccessFile rafTemp = new RandomAccessFile(finalFile, "r");
```

"/data/local/tmp" is the path for the file. It can differ file to file. So you must know the path of file before accessing it.